# How do you give a namespace an alias in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a large namespace: Foo.Bar.Space.Station.Bar and I was to alias is as something shorter like, Station.  How do I do that in the using section?

using Foo.Bar.Space.Station.Bar Object  ???

so I can do this

Station.Object obj = new ...

instead of

Foo.Bar.Space.Station.Bar.Object obj = new ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can give an alias to a namespace in a using statement.

```
using Station = Foo.Bar.Space.Station.Bar;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
using Station = Foo.Bar.Space.Station.Bar;
```

But in my opinion, having two namespaces named Bar is not a very good idea. :) Even if it's not real code.

Answer (score -4):

```
using Foo.Bar.Space.Station.Bar = Station;
```