# Namespace - Blue Prism - Alias

Tags: c#, namespaces, ambiguous, blueprism

Someone knows how I can give an alias for a namespace?

I'm trying to use the namespace `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` but it is generating an ambiguous error.

> Description: Compiler error at line 5140: 'Exception' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Exception' and 'System.Exception'

I read on the internet that I need give an alias for one of two.. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you give a namespace an alias in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202348/how-do-you-give-a-namespace-an-alias-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I can't do that on the global code of blue prism... :(

Comment: Try to reference Microsoft Outlook Object Library instead. Is Blue Prism MAPIEx not good for your needs?

Answer (score 1):

In each Exception object you declare, you should specify the object type since you're using two namespaces that both of them have the Exception type, You should distinguish between them.

So instead of:

```
Exception ex = new Exception();
```

Do:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Exception ex = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Exception();
```

Or:

```
System.Exception ex = new System.Exception();
```

Depending on which exception type you're using.